# Processing XML Data through jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a sample XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
 <person>
         <name> Joe </name>
         <age> 45 </age>
 </person>
<person>
   <name> Dan </name>
   <age> 25 </age>
</person>
</people>
```

The idea is to pull the name of each person using jQuery.
I am finding difficulties in using `$.ajax( { } );` call to pull the data.

How to clean up the following sample code?

```
$.ajax( {
              url:"people.xml",  
              dataType: "json", 
              success:function(element,value)
                  {
                    $(element).find(value).each(function() 
                                        {
                                         alert($(this).find("name").text()
                                         });
                  });
                                         }
           }
        );
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Is the Xml the response from the ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all since you are retrieving `XML` you must set `dataType` to XML.

Then some parentheses fixes to your code and it should work

```
$.ajax({
    url: "people.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find('name').each(function () { // get the names from data
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/TJbsN/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataType` is wrong.You must change it to `"xml"`.

You can change your code something like:

```
$.ajax(
       {
         url:"people.xml ",  //please specify the correct path
         dataType: "xml",    //Here the data type is XML
         success:function(data)
          {
           // if the parsing of the URL
           // is successful this anonymous call get executed
            $(data).find("person")
                   .each(
                         function() 
                         {
                           alert($(this).find("name").text());
                         }
                        );
          });

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

name of each person can be pulled like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "people.xml",
    success: function(data) {
        var names = $(data).find('name');
        $.each(names, function(i, name) {
            alert($(name).text());
        });
    }
});
```